# If $X$ is inductive, then the set $U = \{ x \in X : x \subset X \}$ is inductive

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $N = \cap \{ X : X $ is inductive $ \}$

A set $T$ is transitive if $x \in T$ implies $x \subset T$

I am trying to prove that:

> If $X$ is inductive, then the set $U = \{ x \in X : x \subset X \}$ is inductive. Hence $N$ is transitive, and for each $n$, $n = \{ m \in N | m < n\}$

Proof: Let $\alpha \in U$. We have to show that $\alpha \cup \{ \alpha \} \in U$. But, we know that $\alpha \in X$ and that $X$ is inductive which implies that $\alpha \cup \{ \alpha \} \in X$. But we also know also $\alpha \subset X$ which implies $\alpha \cup \{ \alpha \} \subset X$.

Is my proof ok?

Correction: Also note that $\emptyset \in U$ since $X$ is inductive so, $\emptyset \in X$ and, obviously, $\emptyset \subset X$

Comment: If your definition of inductive includes that $\emptyset$ is an element of an inductive set $X$, then you still need to make a comment about why $\emptyset\in U$ (but this is pretty straight-forward).

Comment: Will be fixed thank you